# Paypal sandbox unable to complete journey in browser headless mode

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am running a test whereby user signs up and chooses Paypal payment method. The test runs using selenium webdriver (3.14.1). It passes when running in chrome browser *non* headless mode, but fails in headless mode.

In headless mode when I log into Paypal I am redirected to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?../checkout/selectFi URL which has `Continue` button. When this cta is clicked I get Paypal sandbox consent page with below button html

```
<div id="button" class="buttons reviewButton">
     <input track-submit="" type="submit" value="Agree and Continue" id="confirmButtonTop" class="btn full confirmButton continueButton" ng-disabled="onPayButtonDisabled" data-test-id="continueButton" validate-submit="onPay()">
</div>
```

However when this cta is clicked the button gets disabled and the page freezes. Paypal sandbox never returns to merchant page from this state. Any suggestions how can this be fixed?

*Note: for same test when run in headful mode the Paypal URL is diffrent. Its https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?../billingweb/review, whereby consent cta is present. And this works fine.*

Thanks

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Hello, I recommend that you use WATIR, which is a wrapper around the Ruby Selenium binding. Then, using the WATIR tag, ask your question.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, Thanks for the direction. It was an issue with Capybara binding.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with Capybara binding. It seems that sometime Capybara trigger a click event on cta so `button.click` doesn't work.

I managed to fix this by dispatching a click on button     `page.execute_script("document.querySelector('input[id=\"confirmButtonTop\"]').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))")`